# Javascript Automatic Links, Loops

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, hyperlink, youtube

I'm very new to coding, and I'm trying to make a script (to put in a Chrome bookmark) that downloads YouTube videos in a click.

To start off, I have a script from TubeOffline.com that is used as the content of a bookmark. The script takes the URL of a YouTube video and makes it into a downloadable link.

The following is the code:

```
javascript:(function(){var openWindow=window.open('http://www.tubeoffline.com/downloadFrom.php');
var url=window.document.URL.toString();
var src=document.documentElement.innerHTML;var 
note='book';form=document.createElement('form');
form.setAttribute('method','POST');
form.setAttribute('action','http://www.tubeoffline.com/downloadFrom.php');
srcPlaceholder=document.createElement('input');
srcPlaceholder.setAttribute('name','src');
srcPlaceholder.setAttribute('type','hidden');
srcPlaceholder.setAttribute('value',src);
form.appendChild(srcPlaceholder);
urlPlaceholder=document.createElement('input');
urlPlaceholder.setAttribute('name','url');
urlPlaceholder.setAttribute('type','hidden');
urlPlaceholder.setAttribute('value',url);
form.appendChild(urlPlaceholder);
notePlaceholder=document.createElement('input');
notePlaceholder.setAttribute('name','note');
notePlaceholder.setAttribute('type','hidden');
notePlaceholder.setAttribute('value',note);
form.appendChild(notePlaceholder);
openWindow.document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();})();
```

[What the bookmark looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVI23.png)

[What the output looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXoZN.png)

I want to add code to the script to automatically click the download link (in highest quality.)

After that I want to be able to put in a list of URLs and have a for loop loop the script over them.